# Disable miniframes but keep the background title rectangle on the title page

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

For aesthetic reasons, I would like to disable the text of the header bar on my title page.

This is what I have :
[image: What I have]

And this is what I would like : 
[image: What I want]

Is there an easy way to do this ? I couldn't find anything other than `\begin{frame}[plain]` but this also removes the colored rectangles.

Here is my current code :

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}

\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=AntiqueWhite4}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10}

\title{Presentation}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Sub 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 4):

Replacing the first frame with the following should do the trick:

```
{
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{mytheme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\phantom{\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}
```

Here is a little how to: I went to the definition of the miniframes theme (search for `beamerouterthememiniframes.sty`) copied the part of the headline definition, changed the theme name and made the \insertnavigation invisible. There was also a part for the "subsection" option of the theme. This part I removed, since you disabled subsections.

Answer (score 2):

I finally came with the solution of hiding it by setting the same color for foreground and background, and then reverting the foreground to black :

```
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black!10,bg=black!10}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black!10,bg=black!10}

\title{Presentation}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10}
```